# Tesseract and multiple line license plates: How can I get characters from a two line license plate?

Tags: python-tesseract

i tried getting individual characters from the image and passing them through the ocr, but the result is jumbled up characters. Passing the whole image is at least returning the characters in order but it seems like the ocr is trying to read all the other contours as well.

example image:
[Image being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyBog.jpg)

The result :  6A7J7B0

Desired result :  AJB6779

The code

```
img = cv2.imread("data/images/car6.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# resize image to three times as large as original for better readability
gray = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx = 3, fy = 3, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
# perform gaussian blur to smoothen image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

# threshold the image using Otsus method to preprocess for tesseract
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# create rectangular kernel for dilation
rect_kern = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
# apply dilation to make regions more clear
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, rect_kern, iterations = 1)

# find contours of regions of interest within license plate
try:
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
except:
    ret_img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# sort contours left-to-right
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
# create copy of gray image
im2 = gray.copy()
# create blank string to hold license plate number
plate_num = ""
# loop through contours and find individual letters and numbers in license plate
for cnt in sorted_contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    height, width = im2.shape
    # if height of box is not tall enough relative to total height then skip
    if height / float(h) > 6: continue

    ratio = h / float(w)
    # if height to width ratio is less than 1.5 skip
    if ratio < 1.5: continue

    # if width is not wide enough relative to total width then skip
    if width / float(w) > 15: continue

    area = h * w
    # if area is less than 100 pixels skip
    if area < 100: continue

    # draw the rectangle
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2)
    # grab character region of image
    roi = thresh[y-5:y+h+5, x-5:x+w+5]
    # perfrom bitwise not to flip image to black text on white background
    roi = cv2.bitwise_not(roi)
    # perform another blur on character region
    roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi, 5)
    try:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --psm 8 --oem 3')
        # clean tesseract text by removing any unwanted blank spaces
        clean_text = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', text)
        plate_num += clean_text
    except:
        text = None
if plate_num != None:
    print("License Plate #: ", plate_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me psm mode 11 worked able to detect single line and multi as well

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--oem 3 --psm 11').replace("\n", ""))
```

11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but am hoping to keep the ocr from trying to read anything that isnt a character of a particular on the number plate whilst maintaining the order of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract license plate number from two rows you can replace following line:

```
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0] + cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[1] * img.shape[1] )
```

with

```
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
```

Comment: i am trying to get characters from both single row and two row number plates, some two row number plates are giving me the desired results with this solution, but others are giving me jumbled results. On top of that, the single row plates are now giving jumbled results. Thanks for the response

Comment: I guess we should use the Regular Expression here, I did not find the proper solution to this problem yet.